# Embedded C : Function-Parameters have erroneous values, while array works

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

for a calculation I have a function with 9 float values, that works most of the time, but sometimes some of the values have erroneous values. I have checked that the code is not re-entered, this does not seem to be the case.

If I use an array instead, it works without any issues.

I’m a little stuck, I do not know what the cause might be, any ideas? The Code is running on a STM32G4/ARM-Cortex-M4.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards, Seppel

**Code that invokes the function with wrong parameters**

Sometimes I get erroneous values, but not all the time, could be a cast-issue, I already increased the Stack to 1k and set the HW-Breakpoint outside and inside and could not find any reason for a reentrant issue.

```
// Variables
float calculatedData[3U];
int16_t sensorValues[3U][3U];

static float AModelParamter[55];
static float BModelParamter[55];
static float CModelParamter[55];

//Functions

void calculation(float* calculatedData, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c )
{
    calculatedData[0]= singleCalc(AModelParamter, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c );
    calculatedData[1]= singleCalc(BModelParamter, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c );
    calculatedData[2]= singleCalc(CModelParamter, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c );
}

float singleCalc(float* a, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c );
{

    float cResult = 0.0;

     cResult = cResult + a[0] ;
     cResult = cResult + a[1]*S1a ;
     cResult = cResult + a[2]*S1b ;
     cResult = cResult + a[3]*S1c ;
     cResult = cResult + a[4]*S2a ;
     cResult = cResult + a[5]*S2b ;
     cResult = cResult + a[6]*S2c ;
     cResult = cResult + a[7]*S3a ;
     cResult = cResult + a[8]*S3b ;
     cResult = cResult + a[9]*S3c ;
     cResult = cResult + a[10]*S1a*S1a ;
     // Many more lines

    return cResult;
}

//Executed Code

osMessageQueueGet(Queue_PositionCalcHandle, sensorValues, 0, portMAX_DELAY);

calculation((calculatedData,
                sensorValues[0U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[0U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[0U][2U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][2U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][2U] * 0.025f);
```

**Code that invokes the function with the write parameters and works**

If I write the values to an array and use a pointer to the values, it works flawlessly.

```
// Function-Interface 
void calculation(float* pReturnArray, float physicalValues[3][3]  )

//Function-Call


float calculatedData[3U];
int16_t sensorValues[3U][3U]; //

osMessageQueueGet(Queue_PositionCalcHandle, sensorValues, 0, portMAX_DELAY);

physicalValues[0U][0U] = (float)(sensorValues[0U][0U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[0U][1U] = (float)(sensorValues[0U][1U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[0U][2U] = (float)(sensorValues[0U][2U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[1U][0U] = (float)(sensorValues[1U][0U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[1U][1U] = (float)(sensorValues[1U][1U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[1U][2U] = (float)(sensorValues[1U][2U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[2U][0U] = (float)(sensorValues[2U][0U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[2U][1U] = (float)(sensorValues[2U][1U]) * 0.025f;
physicalValues[2U][2U] = (float)(sensorValues[2U][2U]) * 0.025f;

calculation(calculatedData, physicalValues);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. Perhaps the problem is in the `calculation` function? Also, it's important that the code you show doesn't contain any other unrelated errors, because the "non-working" code you show do have an error that would lead to the code not building.

Comment: The suffixes on the integer constants are superfluous and just cluttering the code hurting the readability

Comment: Parameters are probably passed on stack. If you have many of these and a limited stack space (or some bug involving stack violation) it would affect your codes in different ways.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm new on stackoverflow, how can I leave along comment with additional code?

Comment: Just click the [edit] button and add the extra info to the question

Comment: @EugeneSh. I changed from a 3*220 to a 3*55 model, then the errors occured.

After seeing the errors I went from a 128 Byte stack to a 1024Byte Stack for the FreeRTOS Task, it did not help.

Comment: Seeing more of the code tells me one thing: Don't use separate arguments. The code can become better, easier to read and maintain, using arrays and loops. So don't bother with the non-working code, focus on improving the working code that's using arrays. Also note that passing more than a few arguments is an *anti-pattern*, and the solution is almost always arrays. That or structures (which doesn't seem to make sense for your use-case).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure, I agree, and I will rework it. However, I like to understand the reason why it did not work and created that.

Comment: Then I recommend you write a new question focusing on that issue specifically. In it mention in passing that it seems to work when using an array as argument, but you don't have to get into too much detail about that. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `calculatedData[0]= singleCalc(AModelParamter, float S1a, float S1b, float S1c, float S2a, float S2b, float S2c, float S3a, float S3b, float S3c );` That code cannot compile as you musn't add types in the function call. This means, you use something different from what you show us. As we do not see what you really do, we cannot be sure what your error is, but only guess

Comment: Where do you initialize `AModelParamter` et. al.?

Comment: @Clifford I was speaking of integer constants, not floats (as in array indices and dimensions)

Comment: @EugeneSh.  You even said "Integer constants"!  My apologies.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if the Stack is sized lage enough(Generally and for the FreeRTOS Task), I may have to check that on the ST-Forum, havn't found any specific fuctionality in ST's IDE to do that dynamically.

@Gerhardh Sorry, I had to alter the code for the example, and I messed that up.
->CraigEstey Yes I do initialize it with floats and the overwrite it with values from the Flash-EEPROM-Emulation.
->Clifford The FPU may not used in this case, not sure if the compiler does, but the is a DSP-Lib that I also have included and may use in a later stage

Comment: What is your underlying RTOS (the one that the CMSIS RTOS API is implemented on)?  What stack did you increase - the one for the thread this code is running in?  What context does this code run in?  Note also that `portMAX_DELAY` is a FreeRTOS constant whilst `osMessageQueueGet()` is an CMSIS RTOS API call - you should not mix the two APIs - at least not in a single function call.  Use `osWaitForever` for a blocking queue wait.

Comment: One of the main benefits of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, that you notice any such error before you post the question, because you compile the exact same code that you then copy into the question.

Comment: Variable names like `A...[]`, `B...[]`, `S1a`, `S2b`, etc. tells me that those should be arrays anyway.

Comment: You really need or know whether the FPU is in use or not and whether FreeRTOS supports it.  Even if that is not your problem right now, it is still a problem.

Comment: I think individual parameters would be passed in registers, the array would be stored in memory. Maybe an interrupt handler is not properly preserving the registers?

Comment: See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432137/how-to-enable-fpu-in-cubemx regarding enabling or disabling the FPU in code.  Not sure if there is an IDE configuration for that I do not use CubeIDE, but somewhere in your start-up code there is likely to be come configuration of CPAR.  Determining whether your compiler generates FPU code or not is determined by your build settings.

Comment: @JohnBayko If it is APCS compliant, only the first four arguments will be passed in registers. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0041/c/ARM-Procedure-Call-Standard/APCS-definition/APCS-register-names-and-roles

Comment: @JohnBayko ... though for FP arguments the FPU registers may be used - therein I think lies the problem - that and preemption.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using U suffix is common best practice, required for MISRA C. Although MISRA C only requires it when you explicitly need something to be unsigned. Array sizes are to be regarded as `size_t` so U suffix makes perfect sense, even though it doesn't add anything in terms of safety there.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `osMessageQueueGet()` suggest that you are using a CMSIS RTOS, and the STM32G4 incorporates a single precision FPU. In order for *hardware floating point operations* to be safe in a multithreaded environment, the FPU registers must be stacked on a context switch.  Otherwise some pre-empting thread may modify the FPU registers mid way through some operation by the task that was preempted.

While FPU operations in multi-threading without explicit FPU context support is in any event dangerous, here the APCS allows floating point arguments to be passed in floating point registers.  With 8 such arguments it is likely that some will be in FPU registers and some on the stack.  A preemption whilst the function call frame is being established by a thread that modifies the FPU registers will cause those parameters passed in FPU registers to be modified on return to the original context.

When you pass a pointer to an array of floats, the pointer is passed in a regular register which will certainly be preserved in an RTOS context switch.  Which is very probably why that code works.  However the result of your multiply-accumulate is unlikely to be correct.  If preemption can corrupt the FPU registers on the function call it is almost certainly doing it to them during other operations - only you may not notice unless you observe the output signal (assuming this is a DSP application).

`osMessageQueueGet()` looks like a CMSIS RTOS call.  The underlying RTOS may or may not support floating-point threads.  Keil RTX supports then and stacks the FPU registers for *all* context switches unconditionally.  Other underlying RTOS may require you to specify which threads use floating point in order to selectively stack the FPU only for "FP threads".  That is efficient but error prone.  Some RTOS may not support hardware floating-point at all.  In that case  your solutions are either:

- Disable H/W FP, and build for SoftFP
- Avoid floating point code altogether, use fixed-point / integer math instead.
- Wrap your floating point operations in a critical section to prevent preemption until a final result is obtained.
- Perform all floating point operations in a single thread.

Without any other changes if you do...

```
uint32_t lock = osKernelLock();

calculation((calculatedData,
                sensorValues[0U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[0U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[0U][2U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[1U][2U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][0U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][1U] * 0.025f,
                sensorValues[2U][2U] * 0.025f);

if( lock ) osKernelUnlock();
```

... and it all seems to start working, then FPU context preservation is your issue.  However I would not recommend that as a solution, merely an experiment to demonstrate that that is the cause.  It does not fix the fundamental problem - merely sweeps it under the carpet for you to trip over then lump later.

Equally your use of arrays only "appears" to work - it has just hidden that symptom of the problem, almost certainly other FP operations will be failing.

Comment: The osMessageQueueGet() get's integer values, these are ok, I checked those of course. When call the function and do the calculation of the physical values from the sensor-increments, it seems as that sporadically introduces an error. Currently I can't even reproduce it. From a FreeRTOS-Task, why should a call to a function using floats cause an issue?

Comment: In the FreeRTOS-Config in the STM32CubeIDE, the FPU is enabled.

Comment: @seppeltronics_v What I think that Clifford wants to tell you is that when you use multiple arguments, there's a chance that the thread might be preempted in the middle of processing the arguments, and that will lead to invalid FPU state and invalid calculations when the thread starts running again.

Comment: The nature of the messages passed in the message queue is irrelevant.  I only mentioned that as evidence that you are using an RTOS because you never mentioned it in your question, and it is critical to the safe cooperation of floating point code.  With respect to your other points about sporadic errors and why float matters, I have covered all that in the answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  : Yes, but not only that - an non-atomic FP operation may be preempted so , not just during a function call.  It turns out that in the APCS passing FP arguments in FPU registers is optional - may or may not happen.  Updating the answer.

Comment: @seppeltronics_v : You need to mention FreeRTOS and CMSIS RTOS in your question if I am to address this directly in the answer rather then a comment, but neither support per-task FPU support via their API.  The Keil RTX5 implementation of CMSIS simply preserves all FPU registers for all tasks.  AFAIK whether FreeRTOS supports FPU is port specific.

Comment: I would probably recommend to keep hardware floating point (such a waste to use software fp while there is a FPU) but encapsulate floating point calculations better. If all calculations are carried out by a single process and the rest of the program just passes calculated values around, then the problem would disappear. But then this may or may not be feasible depending on how large the program is. Also sticking to fixed point whenever possible is always a good idea, nothing in the post looks like it actually _needs_ to be fp.

Comment: @Clifford : 1) What I understood is, that using an RTOS that supports the FPU is a good thing, in general. Do you have any recommendations( avoiding potential pitfalls) for FreeRTOS and the GCC for supporting the FPU?     2)  If I use the FPU in an ISR that does not preempt an FreeRTOS-Task I would guess the registers of the FPU are not stacked/saved, and therefor may be corrupted on return from the ISR. How can I do the configuration that this is done, or how do I implement it manually? Thank you very much, Best Regards, Seppel

Comment: You should not ask run-on questions and in comments.  Post new questions to get the widest possible audience.  You really don't want to get into the habit of floating point operations in interrupt handlers.  If you think that is necessary when you are using an RTOS, then your design is flawed.  The interrupt merely needs to trigger a task thread to perform the calculation. And remember FreeRTOS is free for a good reason, you couldn't sell it!